# Animation bug on navigational links on a mobile menu

Tags: javascript, css

I have mobile navigation bar that toggles on clicking the burger and everything works fine. The navigational links have animation that needs to be triggered every time when there is no animation on them (achieved with JavaScript, code will be shown below) and everything works fine until the moment I click on one navigational link. So the navigation bar closes, and the animation is triggered on closing, thus not on opening and the next time I click on the burger in order to open the menu the animation does not play. BUT, the thing that confuses me the most is that after clicking on one of the navigational links, on the next menu-opening the animation is here and everything works fine (the bug comes after clicking on one of the navigational links).

**How to make the animation play every time on opening the menu?**

HTML code:

```
 <nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#" class="brand">Portfolio</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#main">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

CSS code:

```
// if nav is active translate him to 0 (since he is translated)
.nav-active {
transform: translateX(0%);
}

.nav-links {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
height: 93vh;
top: 7vh;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 0 5px 50px white;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
width: 40%;
transform: translateX(110%);
transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
  .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .nav-links a {
        margin-left: 0;
        color: #3e689d;
        font-size: 2.2em;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        transition: 0.5s ease;
        padding: 30px 30px;
    }
.burger div {
width: 40px;
height: 5px;
background-color: white;
margin: 5px;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
//animation for burger
.toggle .line1 {
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6.5px, 7.5px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
 background-color: black;
 transform: translateX(-100px) scale(0);
}

.toggle .line3 {
 transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6.5px,-7.5px);
}
// animation for links
@keyframes navLinkFade {
from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0) rotate(90deg);
}

to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
 }
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
const navSlide = () => {
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
const navigationItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links a');

// if there is no animation on the links add the one that I have declared in CSS
burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        // I think the problem is in this if/else statement
        if (link.style.animation) {
            link.style.animation = ''
        }
        else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
        }
    });
    // toggle the burger animation that I have declared in CSS
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    // close the menu and the burger on clicking on one of the navigational links
    navigationItems.forEach((navigationItem) => {
        navigationItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
            nav.classList.remove('nav-active');
            burger.classList.remove('toggle');
        });
    });
});
}
navSlide();
```

**Thank you, grateful for any help.**

Comment: Please add the necessary HTML and CSS to your question in order to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added the html and css code.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that I forgot to remove the animation in the event listener that had the task to close the navigation bar and the problem was occurring because the navigation bar was closing but the navigational links still had the animation on them. So to solve my problem I just needed to add two lines of code that will remove the animation when the navigation bar closes.

Here is the solution :

```
navigationItems.forEach((navigationItem) => {
        navigationItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
           //I was missing the next two lines of code to remove the animation from my navigational links when the navigational bar closes
            navLinks.forEach((link) => {
                link.style.animation = ''
            });
            nav.classList.remove('nav-active');
            burger.classList.remove('toggle');
        });
    });
```

**Problem solved.**